# Is there any way to have the Ripple effect's color be dynamic in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm using the ripple effect on clickable elements in my user interface for my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/MenuGray">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

The issue is that I want there to be a ripple effect on elements that have different background colors. Is there any way to have the ripple color be dynamic so it'll be a shade darker than the element that's being clicked on, or do I need to have multiple ripple.xml files for every element with a different background color?

Answer (score 2):

If you load the `RippleDrawable` you should be able to [set the color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html#setColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)).

> public void setColor (ColorStateList color)
>
> Sets the ripple color.

Here is an example that changes the `RippleDrawable` for a couple of `TextViews`.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        setRippleColor(textView, Color.RED);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        setRippleColor(textView, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));

    }

    private void setRippleColor(View view, int color) {
        RippleDrawable drawable = (RippleDrawable) view.getBackground();
        ColorStateList stateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}},
                new int[]{color}
        );
        drawable.setColor(stateList);
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Make it red"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Make it blue"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ripple_drawable.xml**

```
<ripple android:color="@android:color/darker_gray">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</ripple>
```

You may also find ["Programmatically create a RippleDrawable of any color"](https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-programmatically-create-a-rippledrawable-of-any-color/) helpful.